# What is the purpose of nix-instantiate? What is a store-derivation?

Tags: nixos, nix

In the [manual](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-instantiate) it is written :

> The command `nix-instantiate` generates store derivations from
>   (high-level) Nix expressions.

But what are store derivations ?

The manual says the following about [store derivations](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#gloss-derivation) :

> A description of a build action. The result of a derivation is a store
>   object. Derivations are typically specified in Nix expressions using
>   the derivation primitive. These are translated into low-level store
>   derivations (implicitly by `nix-env` and `nix-build`, or explicitly by
>   `nix-instantiate`)

This is a little bit difficult to understand for a nix-newbee and I found nothing more enlightening about `nix-instantiate` and store derivations by googling. I also asked on #nixos, I got no answer, yet.

Could someone please explain on a simple example what a store derivation is, what is it used for ?

Why one would generate store derivations using `nix-instantiate`? Could you give a super simple, easy to understand example ?

Comment: Here's a [short summary on derivations](https://medium.com/scientific-breakthrough-of-the-afternoon/closure-vs-derivation-in-the-nix-package-manager-ec0eccc53407), but it is taken entirely from  Eelco Dolstra’s (the creator of Nix and NixOS) [PhD thesis](https://nixos.org/~eelco/pubs/phd-thesis.pdf). His [list of publications](https://nixos.org/~eelco/pubs/) is also worth to look at.

Answer (score 38):

> What is nix-instantiate good for ?

The command `nix-instantiate` sole purpose is to evaluate Nix expressions.
The primary purpose of the Nix languages is to generate derivations.

> What is a store-derivation?

A derivation ([see example](https://nbp.github.io/slides/NixOS-Paris/Nix-Yet-Another-Package-Manager/index.html?full#build-recipes)) is a computer-friendly representation of the build recipes used for building (realize) packages.  They are files with the extension `.drv` which are listed in the store directory, usually `/nix/store`.

These build recipes are understood by the Nix daemon, and are used to ensure that all the dependencies are built before, and stored in the pre-computed paths.  Once all dependencies are successfully compiled, then the Nix daemon can look for substitute, or realize the derivation locally.  All the detailed explanation is available in [Eelco Dolstra PhD Thesis](http://nixos.org/~eelco/pubs/phd-thesis.pdf).

These files are created each time the `nix-instantiate` command evaluates the `derivation` function of the Nix language, unless the `--eval` command line option is provided.

> Why one would generate store derivations using `nix-instantiate` ?

If you are interested in the build output, you should prefer `nix-build`, which is equivalent to:

`$ nix-store -r $(nix-instantiate '<nixpkgs>' -A hello)`

In some cases you are not interested in the build results, but in looking at the compilation time dependencies.  For example, if you want you to investigate the build time dependencies of the `hello` package.  Then using the `nix-store` command as follow, you can request all the dependencies of the build recipe:

`$ nix-store --tree -q $(nix-instantiate '<nixpkgs>' -A hello)`

Comment: @jhegedus: If this answer answers your queries, please accept it. It is a stackoverflow-way of saying `Many thanks`.

Answer (score 10):

EDIT: this whole thing needs to be revised, because it is very misleading; for example:

- A derivation is **not** function application, but taking a Nix expression and translate it and its concrete arguments to an alternative format.

---

<sup>All quotes are from [Eelco Dolstra's PhD thesis](https://nixos.org/%7Eeelco/pubs/phd-thesis.pdf).</sup>

### Store derivations

A  **store derivation**  is  a  [Nix  expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58243555/1498178)  with  all
variability removed and ***translated***  into an alternative format.
This   intermediate  representation   "*describes  a
single,  static,  constant build  action*" that can be ***built*** into software components.

<sup>"*Nix expressions usually translate to a graph of store derivations.*"</sup>

To put it differently,

```
*------------------------------------------------------*
|                                                      |
| NIX EXPRESSION == function                           |
|                                                      |
| ( Describes how to build a component. That is, how ) |
| ( to  compose  its  input parameters, which can be ) |
| ( other components as well.                        ) |
|                                                      |
| STORE DERIVATION == function application             |
|                                                      |
| ( Result of a Nix expression called with concrete arguments. ) |
| ( Corollary: a single Nix  expression  can produce ) |
| ( different derivations depending on the inputs.   ) |
|                                                      |
*------------------------------------------------------*
```

For context:

[image: Two-stage building of Nix expressions. nix-instantiate translates Nix expressions into store derivations, and nix-store --realize builds the derivation into a software component.]
<sup>Image taken from section "2.4 Store derivations".</sup>

---

The [thesis](https://nixos.org/%7Eeelco/pubs/phd-thesis.pdf) describes a Nix expression as
a "*family  of  build  actions*", in  contrast  to  a
derivation that is "*exactly one build action*".

```
                              ARG_1, ..., ARG_N

                        | ---(aaa, ...)---> DERIVATION_1
        NIX EXPRESSION  | ---(bbb, ...)---> DERIVATION_2
                        |       :
           function(    |       :
             param_1,   |       :
             ...,       |       :
             param_N    |       :
             )          |       :
                        | ---(zzz, ...)---> DERIVATION_N
```

The derivations  above could  be producing  the same
application but  would build it with different configuration
options  for example.  (See APT  packages `vim-nox`,
`vim-gtk`, `vim-gtk3`, `vim-tiny`, etc.)

#### Why is it called "derivation"?

Its name comes from "*2.2 Nix expressions*":

> The result  of the  function [i.e.,  Nix expression]
> is  a  **derivation**.  This   is  Nix-speak  for  a
> **component  build  action**,  which  *derives*  the
> component from its inputs.

#### Why are "store derivations" needed?

Section  "*2.4 Store  derivations*" has  all the
details, but here's the gist:

> Nix expressions are not built directly; rather, they are translated to
> the more primitive language of store derivations, which encode single
> component build actions. This is analogous to the way that compilers
> generally do the bulk of their work on simpler intermediate
> representations of the code being compiled, rather than on a fullblown
> language with all its complexities.

#### Format of store derivations

From section  "5.4. Translating  Nix expressions to store derivations":

> The abstract syntax of store derivations is shown in Figure 5.5 in a
> Haskell-like [135] syntax (see Section 1.7). The store derivation
> example shown in Figure 2.13 is a value of this data type.
>
> Figure 5.5.: Abstract syntax of store derivations

```
 data StoreDrv = StoreDrv {    
   output : Path,              
   outputHash : String,        
   outputHashAlgo : String,    
   inputDrvs : [Path],         
   inputSrcs : [Path],         
   system : String,            
   builder : Path,             
   args : [String],            
   envVars : [(String,String)] 
 }
```

#### Example

For example, the Nix expression to build the `Hello`
package in Figure 2.6,

> Figure 2.6
>
> ```hs
> {stdenv, fetchurl, perl}:
>
> stdenv.mkDerivation {
>   name = "hello-2.1.1";
>   builder = ./builder.sh;
>   src = fetchurl {
>     url = http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/hello/hello-2.1.1.tar.gz;
>     md5 = "70c9ccf9fac07f762c24f2df2290784d";
>   };
>   inherit perl;
> }
> ```

will  result in  an  intermediate representation  of
something similar to in Figure 2.13:

> Figure 2.13 Store derivation
>
> ```
> { output = "/nix/store/bwacc7a5c5n3...-hello-2.1.1" 25
> , inputDrvs = { 26
>     "/nix/store/7mwh9alhscz7...-bash-3.0.drv",
>     "/nix/store/fi8m2vldnrxq...-hello-2.1.1.tar.gz.drv",
>     "/nix/store/khllx1q519r3...-stdenv-linux.drv",
>     "/nix/store/mjdfbi6dcyz7...-perl-5.8.6.drv" 27 }
>   }
> , inputSrcs = {"/nix/store/d74lr8jfsvdh...-builder.sh"} 28
> , system = "i686-linux" 29
> , builder = "/nix/store/3nca8lmpr8gg...-bash-3.0/bin/sh" 30
> , args = ["-e","/nix/store/d74lr8jfsvdh...-builder.sh"] 31
> , envVars = { 32
>     ("builder","/nix/store/3nca8lmpr8gg...-bash-3.0/bin/sh"),
>     ("name","hello-2.1.1"),
>     ("out","/nix/store/bwacc7a5c5n3...-hello-2.1.1"),
>     ("perl","/nix/store/h87pfv8klr4p...-perl-5.8.6"), 33
>     ("src","/nix/store/h6gq0lmj9lkg...-hello-2.1.1.tar.gz"),
>     ("stdenv","/nix/store/hhxbaln5n11c...-stdenv-linux"),
>     ("system","i686-linux"),
>     ("gtk","/store/8yzprq56x5fa...-gtk+-2.6.6"),
>   }
> }
> ```

> The abstract syntax of store derivations is shown in Figure 5.5 in a
> Haskell-like [135] syntax (see Section 1.7). The store derivation
> example shown in Figure 2.13 is a value of this data type.
>
> Figure 5.5.: Abstract syntax of store derivations

```
 data StoreDrv = StoreDrv {    
   output : Path,              
   outputHash : String,        
   outputHashAlgo : String,    
   inputDrvs : [Path],         
   inputSrcs : [Path],         
   system : String,            
   builder : Path,             
   args : [String],            
   envVars : [(String,String)] 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically in Nix as an end user you start with nix expressions, these can be turned into nix derivations, which can later be "realized"  (which is basically the final built output).

The purpose of `nix-instantiate` is to convert nix expressions into deriviations which are basically intermediate primitives.

---

> Why one would generate store derivations using nix-instantiate? Could
> you give a super simple, easy to understand example ?

This is usually done indirectly (for example via `nix build`).

---

It might be a bit confusing as `/nix/store` is the parent directory that stores both deriviations and realized outputs as well.